# Deleting virtual machine after uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I thought if I uninstalled VM VirtualBox all the virtual machines will be deleted as well, but the free storage space in my computer has not changed, so how can I delete the virtual machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VMs are mostly stored here:

> C:\Users\[username]\VirtualBox VMs

you can just delete them there